# Configuring wondershaper

Tags: ftp

I am currently using wondershaper to limit my bandwidth.

To test out the bandwidth limiter, I have set up FTP transfers using Filezilla and vsftpd server. Both upload and download were set to 100Mbps. However, I can only manage to achieve 100Mbps on the upload side but not 100Mbps on the download. On average, I would only get 2 - 3Mbps for download. Wondering if anyone could shed some light on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the WMM on your router and check your download speed,

Just google on to,

how to disable WMM  ?

Comment: Hi vembutech, I'm transferring files on a wired network. And this 2 - 3 Mbps happens only when wondershaper has been configured. Are there any configuration that I miss out on?